# go environment variable GOGCCFLAGS not setting

Tags: go, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile some Go code for ARM architecture and am running into an issue with the compiler flags.

When I try to build my project I get some undefined errors relating to pcap

```
[brandon@f4998 src]$ go build
# _/home/brandon/IdeaProjects/new-snap/src
./main.go:120: undefined: pcap.OpenLive
./main.go:120: undefined: pcap.BlockForever
```

I assumed this was because I need to include -lpcap when compiling so I set the GOGCCFLAGS environment variable to include -lpcap. However, this does not work because go is reading the $GOGCCFLAGS from somewhere else

```
[brandon@f4998 src]$ export GOGCCFLAGS=-lpcap
[brandon@f4998 src]$ echo $GOGCCFLAGS
-lpcap
[brandon@f4998 src]$ go version
go version go1.5.4 linux/amd64
[brandon@f4998 src]$ go env
GOARCH="arm"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/brandon/IdeaProjects/new-snap"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=""
CC="arm-linux-gnu-gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -marm -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="arm-linux-gnu-g++"
CGO_ENABLED="0"
```

All of the other variables seem to be set correctly, but nothing happens when I set $GOGCCFLAGS

Comment: `GOGCCFLAGS` isn't configurable. What are you trying to do?

Comment: BTW, I also see you have `CGO_ENABLED=0`, so you're not going to be calling a C compiler at all. You also have a very old (and no longer supported) version of Go. You should update to go1.7+ (or try the upcoming go1.8, with huge improvements to the code generated for arm)

Comment: @JimB I think that might be the problem. There seems to be some embedded C code in the google pcap libraries. I am able to compile the program just fine for amd64 with `CGO_ENABLED=0` but when I switch to ARM would I need to enable this?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how you were compiling the package for amd64, but the [`github.com/google/gopacket/pcap`](https://github.com/google/gopacket/blob/master/pcap/pcap.go) package is done completely through cgo.